# Overflow text align left

Tags: html, css

When the description cell overflows it overflows showing the center of the text. How can I make it so the left hand side (the start) is the bit that shows.
If the text doesn't overflow I want it to center still.

the css I am using is the following

```
.td {
    display: flex;
flex-flow: row nowrap;
flex-grow: 1;
flex-basis: 0;
padding: 0.5em;
word-break: break-all;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis ;
min-width: 0px;
white-space: nowrap;
border-bottom: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
}

.td :hover{
white-space: normal;
}
```

Here is a codepen of what I currently have
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rpWpve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, set the `<span>`'s `max-width`

```
.td > span {
  max-width:100%;
}
```

Text was left-aligned within the span, but the span was centered and extended beyond the sides of the div.

Answer (score 2):

You can change `justify-content` for that cell to `flex-start`

```
<div class="td" style="justify-content: flex-start;">
  <span>A really long string of numbers or characters which will overflow</span>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/andrewgi/pen/Leberz

Comment: Thanks, but, I still want it centered even if it does not overflow